# Android how to use rs232 port to receive rs485 data?

Tags: android, serial-port, rs485

My android device has a RS232 port,
and I have a keyboard with the rs232 port,
so I use the "android-serialport-api", 
create an app to receive the keyboard typein, and success.

but,
another keyboard use rs485,
so i use a rs232 to rs485 adapter to convert it.
but the careated app can't get any input data anymore.

Why...? should I create new app for it?
Have any  way can solve this problem?
thanks,all.

Comment: If your RS-232 to RS-485 adapter is port powered, the Android device's RS-232 port might not be providing enough power for it to work.  you might want to check if there's enough power for the converter or try an external power supply if that's an option.

Answer (score 1):

- check wiring (is each wire connected to the right pin)
- try to connect only one device (not two). does it work so?
- verify RS232 levels (volts). there are different implementations (1.8V, TTL) and these levels of adapter and device have to match.
- verify there is enough power provided
- check baud rate and other port settings